# Best Way To Modify A Property Of Elements In A List According To A Grouping

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a `List` of `CartItem`, some of which have identical `Name` properties.
I need all the `Name` properties to be unique. The obvious thing to do is to roll them up into single items with `Quantity` properties > 1, but for reasons that I won't go into, I'm not free to do that. I also don't want to do the ugly, easy thing by just appending a GUID to each name. So I want to append to the `Name` properties a substring like " (1 of 3)", but only for Names that have duplicates. Names that are already unique I want to leave alone, so there's none that say " (1 of 1)".

Here's a unit test for what I'm talking about. I'm trying to come up with a better way to do the lines between the comments:

```
class CartItem
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSOQuestion()
{
   var exampleList = new List<CartItem>
   {
      new CartItem 
         { Name="Same String", UnitPrice=10.00m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
         { Name="Same String", UnitPrice=10.00m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
         { Name="Other String", UnitPrice=14.99m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
         { Name="Other String", UnitPrice=14.99m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
         { Name="Other String", UnitPrice=14.99m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
         { Name="Only One Of This", UnitPrice=29.99m, Quantity=1}
   };

var expectedList = new List<CartItem>
   {
      new CartItem 
        { Name="Same String (1 of 2)", UnitPrice=10.00m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
        { Name="Same String (2 of 2)", UnitPrice=10.00m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
        { Name="Other String (1 of 3)", UnitPrice=14.99m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
        { Name="Other String (2 of 3)", UnitPrice=14.99m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
        { Name="Other String (3 of 3)", UnitPrice=14.99m, Quantity=1},
      new CartItem 
        { Name="Only One Of This", UnitPrice=29.99m, Quantity=1}
   };

        //This is the best I can come up with:
        var groups = exampleList.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                item.Name = item.Name + string.Format(
                               " ({0} of {1})", i++, group.Count());
            }
        }
        //Is there a better way to do this?

        for (int i = 0; i < expectedList.Count(); i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedList[i].Name, exampleList[i].Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks RedHat for the thoughtful answer.

Here's what I ended up using:

```
exampleList.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList().ForEach
(
    group =>
    {
        foreach (var item in group
            .Select((x, i) => new { val = x, idx = i + 1 }))
        {
            item.val.Name += string.Format
            (
                " ({0} of {1})", item.idx, group.Count()
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Rather than projecting the result into a new `List`, I preferred
to selectively modify the `Name` properties in the existing collection.
Since the actual dataset has mostly non-repeating `Name` properties
which would be excluded by the `Where(g => g.Count() > 1)`,
fewer iterations through the nested foreach loops would occur.
Moreover, this `Cart` class was greatly simplified for the sake of the
question; it actually contains many more properties, including a
`Dictionary` of name-value pairs. Having to project each property
into the result would mean tighter coupling to the `Cart` class.
If we were to add or modify a property in the future, this code
would have to be updated as well.
To avoid that maintenance problem, this approach only requires the
existence of a `string Name` property.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result=exampleList.GroupBy(p=>p.Name).SelectMany(p=>p.Select((value,index)=> new CartItem()
            {
                Name = value.Name +
                       (p.Count() == 1?"": string.Format(" ({0} of {1})", index+1, p.Count())),
                UnitPrice=value.UnitPrice,
                Quantity=value.Quantity,
            }
            )).ToList();
```

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify that I don't want to modify names that are already unique, so that none say "...(1 of 1)". Sorry I didn't specify that in the first place.

Comment: I just add a condition if: p.Count() == 1